# Java class inheritance problem: Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

For whatever reason, the compiler is saying i've mistaken a symbol for... the right symbol?

I've seen an error of this type before, for example, if you mistake javascript arrays with java arrays it'll give a similar error, however it'll say the two symbols are mix-matched.

```
int[] pi_digits = [3, 1, 4, 1, 5];
//Should be int[] pi_digits = {3, 1, 4, 1, 5};
```

The error is:

```
Syntax error on token "[", { expected after this token
```

I've already tried (what I thought) were the most obvious solutions - I've completely removed the curly brackets from the second class (luckily this didn't work) and I also tried putting them in the same class, which had the same problems.

The third thing I tried almost solved the problem. For whatever reason, adding a second set of curly brackets solved the problem for the compiler, however in runtime none of the code actually compiled and name and description returned null.

FirstClass file:

```
package p;

abstract class FirstClass {

    String name;
    String description;
    ...
}
```

SecondClass file:

```
package p;

public class SecondClass extends FirstClass { //Error 1 here


    Name = " ... ";
    Description = " ... ";
    ...

} //Error 2 here
```

Error 1: "Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token"

Error 2: "Syntax error on token "}", } expected after this token"

I have no idea what's going wrong, especially since it's saying that the symbol it should have is the one it's detected.

Comment: What JDK version are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure if you elided type declarations in your concrete class for Name and Description, by maybe try parent.name, and parent.description.  Do the errors go away if you reference nothing from the abstract class?

Comment: There are errors in this code, but not these errors. Post the real code, or the real errors.

Comment: Building on what user207421 said, a _minimal_ example of code that produces the error would be helpful, both for us and for you. It would let us find the error more easily, and you might find the error yourself when creating such an example.

Answer (score 3):

I think, your variable initialization was wrong
You can't initialize the parent variables inside the class like what you have done above. you can create one method then you can initialize the parent variables inside the method and invoked the method after the object creation.
Or you can initialize the parent variables inside the constructor which will automatically initialize when you create the B type of object.

```
Class A{
    String a;
    String b;
}
Class B extends A{
   public  B(){
      a = "some name";
      b = " second name";
   }
  public initByMethod(){
     a= " good";
     b= "bad";
   }
}
```

```
//Inside the main method
B object =new B();
System.out.println(object.a);//"some name"
```

When you print b.a it will give the "some name" as an output.
After invoking the method like below then you call, you will get the " good" as an output

```
Inside the main method
object.initByMethod();
System.out.println(object.a);// " good"
```

It may help you

Comment: Yes, you can initialize class-level variables. But what you can't do is to assign values using operators or method calls.

Comment: When we initialize the variables with method you have to invoke it. By default, If you want to initialize you can use those things inside the constructor. By the way, I have updated the answer with the help of @KaNa0011's comment

Answer (score 0):

What went wrong in your second class is that you ommitted the data types in the class-level variables.

```
package p;

public class SecondClass extends FirstClass {

    String name = " ... ";         // Added data type 'String'
    String description = " ... ";  // Added data type 'String'

}
```

Note that this does not necessarily override the fields `name` and `description`. Re-declaring these fields with another data type in another subclass is possible:

```
package p;

public class ThirdClass extends FirstClass {

    int name = 5;
    int description = 6;
}
```